# Python program working in CMD but not when exported to .exe

Tags: python, windows, cmd, exe

I'm having an issue where my python program works correctly when ran from the command prompt but does not function properly when exported to an exe. Specifically I'm having an issue with this section of code, maybe there is a better way of doing this?:

---

```
def select_pcb_num(self, boardDrawingNumber):
    xTuple = XTuple()
    temp = xTuple.find_pcb_item_number(boardDrawingNumber)
    if len(temp)>1:
        iSelect = int(0)
        rawChar = ''
        query = '{0} variants found, select correct board [up/down]: {1}\t\t\t\t'
        sys.stdout.write(query.format(len(temp), temp[iSelect]))
        rawChar = msvcrt.getch()
        while not rawChar == '\r':
            if ord(rawChar) == int(72): # upkey
                iSelect = (iSelect + 1)%len(temp)
            elif ord(rawChar) == int(80): # downkey
                iSelect = (iSelect - 1)%len(temp)
            sys.stdout.write('\r')
            sys.stdout.write(query.format(len(temp), temp[iSelect]))
            rawChar = msvcrt.getch()
        sys.stdout.write('\n')
        return temp[iSelect]
    else:
        return temp
```

In command prompt it correctly returns to the beginning of the line and writes over it when an up or down arrow is pressed. However when exported to an exe it causes the same line to be reprinted and than prints the correct line. Please see the example picture, the lines with the red arrows should not be printed and there shouldn't have been any new lines since I didn't get to the '\n' because no selection was made.

[image]

Update:
Input printed with the method repr() looks like when the down arrow is pressed it first registers as '\xe0' and than as 'P', why would having compiled to an exe cause this? Also I don't see why it's adding a new line since it should be in the while loop

[image: printing input using repr()]

Comment: Try to print the `repr` version of the input to check what's the actual input.

Comment: You may also want to specify how you've "exported to a .exe".

Comment: exported to a .exe using PyInstaller, also tried py2exe same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the documented behaviour of `getch` on Windows. Arrow keys return first either 0x00 or 0xE0, then the key code. See [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak.aspx):

> When reading a function key or an arrow key, each function must be
>   called twice; the first call returns 0 or 0xE0, and the second call
>   returns the actual key code.